# Node js convert mysql data to sqllite

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm

1. In node js i want to  fetch data from mysql and send response as
   sqlite file in rest api like `res.sendFile(sqlite file)`.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am having code like                                                                                     var sql_user_exist = "select * from table";
 connection.query(sql, function(err,result){                                                                     // here fetching result and want to convert this result data in sqlite file and want to send it as a response like res.sendFile(sqlitefile);